# Remove commas from regex javascript

Tags: javascript

I extracted a string and i used regex to return a number, but it returns each number separated by a comma. 
I want to use regex, so I am confused, please help.

```
var getPages = "Pages (226)";
var getPagesNew = getPages.match(/\d/g);
```

This code returns 2,2,6

I need the number without commas, how do I do that? I tried using replace to remove the commas and replace them with nothing but that gave me some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `/\d+/g`

`\d` matches a single digit, so it will match each digit inidividually, hence multiple results.
`\d+` matches `1` or more digits, so it will match as many consecutive digits it finds.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var re = /\((.+)\)/g;
var str = 'Pages (226)';
var m = re.exec(str);
var element = document.getElementById("answer");
element.innerHTML = m[1];
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with method array.join( expression )

```
var getPages = "Pages (226)";
var getPagesNew = getPages.match(/\d/g).join( "" );
```

about this method -> [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

-hi hi, Saludos :)